# How should I clean brake dust off my hands?

Tags: cleaning

Wiped a bunch of brake dust off my car's wheels and got some on my hands; what's a good, responsible way to wash my hands after I get brake dust on them? I don't really know if it's unsafe to get it down your sink like grease (but I kind of assume so).

What should I use to get brake dust off my hands and how should I dispose of it?

Comment: Next time use gloves, and be equally concerned about the effect to your hands & skin as to the effects to your sink

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a real enviromental concern look for a hand cleaner that is citrus based.Wipe your hands on a disposable towel and throw it in the regular trash. Most of us just wash our hand and rinse it down the drain. The brake dust doesn't contain any grease or oils. It is a combination of metal particles,maybe some ceramic particles and binders that hold all the other pad materials together. If the brakes are really old, say thirty years they could contain asbestos. In the grand scheme of things though the brake dust is dipersed into the enviroment every time every single vehicle uses their brakes. The amount on your hands is pretty miniscule.